# c++ Segmentation Fault on method call

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I'm working on assignment where I have to create a deep copy constructor for a given linked list in c++. Inside the copy constructor the code and pointers work fine, but when the print function gets called I get a segmentation fault in the function at line 59:

```
cout << v->elem << " ";
```

I've been trying to debug this for hours and I have no idea why the seg fault occurs. The code for the assignment (only the code in the copy constructor is mine):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stddef.h>
#include "intSLinkedList.h"

using namespace std;

intSLinkedList::intSLinkedList(const intSLinkedList& other){
    if(other.head == NULL){
        this->head = NULL;
    }

    else{
        intSNode* src_cursor = other.head;

        while(src_cursor != NULL){
            this->addFront(src_cursor->elem);
            src_cursor = src_cursor->next;  
        }
    }
}

intSLinkedList::intSLinkedList(): head(NULL), tail(NULL) { }

bool intSLinkedList::empty() const{ return head == NULL; }

const int& intSLinkedList::front() const{ return head->elem; }

//intSLinkedList::~intSLinkedList(){ while (!empty()) removeFront(); }

void intSLinkedList::addFront(const int& e) {// add to front of list
    intSNode* v = new intSNode;          // create new node
    v->elem = e;                         // store data
        v->next = head;                      // head now follows v
        head = v;                            // v is now the head
    if (head->next==NULL)
        tail = head;
}

void intSLinkedList::addBack(const int& e) {// add to front of list
        intSNode* v = new intSNode;          // create new node
        v->elem = e;
    v->next = NULL;                         // store data

    tail->next = v;                      // head now follows v
    tail = v;
}

void intSLinkedList::removeFront() {         // remove front item
        intSNode* old = head;                // save current head
        head = old->next;                    // skip over old head
        delete old;                          // delete the old head
}

void intSLinkedList::print() {
        intSNode* v = head;
        while (v != NULL){
            cout << v->elem << " ";
            v = v->next;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int intSLinkedList::count() {
        intSNode* v = head;
    int n = 0;
        while (v != NULL){
        n++;
                v = v->next;
        }
    return n;
}
```

Header File:

```
class intSLinkedList;

class intSNode { 
private: 
    int elem; 
    intSNode* next;     
    friend class intSLinkedList; 
};

class intSLinkedList { 
public: 
    intSLinkedList();

    intSLinkedList(const intSLinkedList& other);

    bool empty() const;

    const int& front() const;

    //~intSLinkedList();

    void addFront(const int& e);

    void addBack(const int& e);

    void removeFront();

    void print();

    int count();

private: 
    intSNode* head; 
    intSNode* tail;
};
```

and the tester file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "intSLinkedList.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){
    intSLinkedList int_sll;
    int_sll.addFront(5);
    int_sll.addFront(12);
    int_sll.addFront(6);
    cout << "int_sll : ";
    int_sll.print();

    intSLinkedList int_sll2 = int_sll;
    cout << "int_sll2 : ";
        int_sll2.print();

    int_sll.addBack(100);
    cout << "int_sll : ";
    int_sll.print();
    cout << "int_sll2 : ";
        int_sll2.print();

}
```

My GDB output:

```
int_sll : 6 12 5 

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000400cce in intSLinkedList::print (this=0x7fffffffe010)
    at intSLinkedList.cpp:57
57              cout << v->elem << " ";
```

Any help or a point in the right direction is much appreciated.

Comment: You've got your debugger open. Try to step through your code leading up to the fault.

Comment: Most likely, `v` is NULL.

Comment: your addBack will crash if tail is nullptr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you failed to initialize `next` with anything, so it's an undefined value and you're crashing out as you navigate to it.

You don't show all your constructor variants so be sure each constructor *always* initializes *all* properties.